# Transforming SQL into Linq To Objects expressions at runtime

Tags: sql, linq, parsing, expression-trees, sql-to-linq-conversion

Does anyone know of any libraries that one can use to parse a SQL query and build up a linq expression which can then be compiled and used against linq to objects?

This approach only needs to work for simple queries, for complex ones I can write a hardcoded custom query

UPDATE: I've found something called NQuery which should do the trick for me http://nquery.codeplex.com/ so don't waste your time answering!

Comment: I was going to do that in two days when I can accept it

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is a project call [SqlLinq] (https://github.com/dkackman/SqlLinq) which converts SQL into c# Expression Trees, and evaluates them.