# Run SQL statement against grid

Tags: c#, sql, wpf

Is there a possibility to run SQL statements against a datagridview or a gridview?

Comment: against a datagridview means?

Comment: I mean: if I have a datagridview can I do something like "SELECT * FROM dataGridView"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

please refer the [this](http://nquery.codeplex.com/%20.) links that it will convert sql to Linq to objects

Taken from following:

[Transforming SQL into Linq To Objects expressions at runtime](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7023708/transforming-sql-into-linq-to-objects-expressions-at-runtime)

hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

You can make like this>>

```
 dataGridView1.SelectionMode = DataGridViewSelectionMode.FullRowSelect;
   dataGridView1.AllowUserToAddRows = false;
    dataGridView1.AllowUserToDeleteRows = false;
    dataGridView1.AllowUserToOrderColumns = true;
    dataGridView1.ReadOnly = true;
   dataGridView1.MultiSelect = false;
    dataGridView1.AutoSizeRowsMode = DataGridViewAutoSizeRowsMode.None;
    dataGridView1.AllowUserToResizeColumns = false;
    dataGridView1.ColumnHeadersHeightSizeMode = 
    DataGridViewColumnHeadersHeightSizeMode.DisableResizing;
    dataGridView1.AllowUserToResizeRows = false;
    dataGridView1.RowHeadersWidthSizeMode = 
    DataGridViewRowHeadersWidthSizeMode.DisableResizing;
```

You can add columns by `dataGridView1.Columns["CompanyName"].ReadOnly = true;`

Can refer this>>http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cze614bb.aspx

Or simply another way is keep your database table name and gridview name same.

Answer (score 0):

No. But you can try using LINQ to objects instead.

Comment: Do you know a converter that can convert sql to linq-to-objects? Does such a thing exist?